# Laravel Passport with OAuth2 rest api

Tags: laravel, flutter, rest, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

As a Flutter developer using Laravel Passport with OAuth2, I want to know how to use the client token to authenticate my mobile app with the API, and the user token to authenticate individual user requests. I am confused because I only see one type of token in Passport, the client token.

My app is able to show data without the user logging in, but I am not sure if this is secure. Can anyone explain how to use the client token and user token correctly ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.